# Selection of combinations in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

In a path I have files like these:

```
check1
check1_f
check1_f_line
check2
check2_f
check2_f_line
..
```

I want to make a `for` loop that will use in a function combinations of these files.

**Question**

I am not sure how to make these combinations that for each 'check' it will take the correct combination.

The function if it wasn't for the loop it would look like this:

```
erase('check1','check1_f_line','output_name')
```

What I've tried:

```
for i, j in path:
    if 'f' not in i and 'line' in j:
        erase(i, j, i + '_output')
```

---

**Update**

I checked with this list and it has some problems:

```
li=['check3_dwg_Polyline', 'check2_dwg_Polyline', 
'check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg', 
'check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg',
'check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line', 
 'check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line']
```

then this:

```
a=[li[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(li), 3)]
```

where returns:

```
[['check3_dwg_Polyline',
  'check2_dwg_Polyline',
  'check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg'],
 ['check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg',
  'check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line',
  'check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line']]
```

Finally:

```
for base, base_f, base_line in a:
    print(base, base_line, base + "_output")
```

gives:

```
check3_dwg_Polyline  check3_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg  check3_dwg_Polyline_output
check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg  check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line  check2_dwg_Polyline_feat_to_polyg_output
```

Upper combination is correct while the other is not. Any ideas?

---

NEW

For example:

```
base = [f for f in li if not f.endswith(("_polyg", "_to_line"))]
base_f = {f.strip("_polyg"): f for f in li if f.endswith("_polyg")}
base_line = {f.strip("_to_line"): f for f in li if f.endswith("_to_line")}
[(b, base_f[b], base_line[b]) for b in base]
```

gives:

```
KeyError: 'check3_dwg_Polyline'
```

Comment: What output are you getting with that code?

Comment: Are there other files in the directory, and will there always be triplets of files with that exact name pattern?

Comment: So, is `path` the above list of filenames?

Comment: always the same pattern but if you can suggest as well a way in cases where is not a pattern would nice.

Comment: Yes `path` is the list of the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `path` is the list of file names, and assuming that this list contains no files other than those, and assuming that the file names are sorted by name (if they aren't, just sort them), you can just subdivide the list into chunks of three.

```
>>> [path[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(path), 3)]
[['check1', 'check1_f', 'check1_f_line'],
 ['check2', 'check2_f', 'check2_f_line']]
```

Alternatively, you could get the "base" files (without the suffixes), and then the corresponding suffixed files, and then pair them up accordingly. If some of the suffix-files might not exist, you can also use `base_f.get(b)` instead of `base_f[b]`, then those elements will be `None` instead of raising an exception.

```
>>> base = [f for f in path if not f.endswith(("_f", "_f_line"))]
>>> base_f = {f.strip("_f"): f for f in path if f.endswith("_f")}
>>> base_line = {f.strip("_f_line"): f for f in path if f.endswith("_f_line")}
>>> [(b, base_f[b], base_line[b]) for b in base]
[('check1', 'check1_f', 'check1_f_line'),
 ('check2', 'check2_f', 'check2_f_line')]
```

This part of your question is not entirely clear, but you could then iterate either of the two resulting lists of triplets and call `erase` accordingly:

```
for base, base_f, base_line in triples:
    erase(base, base_line, base + "_output")
```

Comment: Ok, say I did the first piece of code you wrote. What is the next step towards the loop and the correct combination for the arguments in the function `erase`?

Comment: Well, you just loop over the triplets in the resulting list and call the function with the corresponding parts? Not sure how exactly you would call `erase`, as that function does not seem to use the `_f` file, but instead some output file. See my edit.

Comment: Actually, it isn't using some output. It is like this: 1st argument=check1, 2nd= check1_f_line and 3d = the name OF the output that will be created if you run the erase function.

Comment: Yes the ` _f` alone is not used later.

Comment: Can you see the updated question where your answer is tested with a case? Thank you, it is almost done.

Comment: @user10110338 That list is not sorted. Sort the list first. Or try the second approach (but then adapt the suffixes to those in that list)

Comment: I have tried both. the sort didn't make it fine and the second approach says `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'`

Comment: The sort just messed it up differently.

Comment: When I try with your list, it works perfectly, and if you get that error, you are probably applying the second approach to the already chunked list of triplets, not to the original list.

Comment: Correct but on the latest list I have changed it to work for that list but gives this error.(Check updated question for new update).What do you think?

Comment: @user10110338 Because you only strip `_to_line`  but you have to strip `_feat_to_polyg_feat_to_line` to get the base name.

Comment: it still gives: KeyError: 'check3_dwg_Polyline'

Comment: @user10110338 Well, I told you why it gives that error and how to fix it, didn't I? If you fixed it (or you think you did) please update the code in your question, and include everything that's needed to reproduce the problem.